# Puedo poner el atributo que yo quiera

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Me interesa saber si es correcto poner el atributo que yo quiera, en este ejemplo puse el atributo *price* ¿hay algún problema de posición o es valido usar los atributos que se requieran en una etiqueta?

```html
<span id="counter" price="250"></span>
```

Comment: Por favor agrega una breve descripción de lo que has buscado/investigado como se sugiere en [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aunque no estaría mal, según la guía de Mozilla, deberías usar `data-*` para este tipo de atributos especiales quedando tal que así `data-price="250"`.

Ya no habría problema en lo que lo uses, si es necesario pars ti que ese atributo esté dentro del HTML de tu etiqueta realmente no hay lío y los diferentes framework y vanilla js lo encontrarán tal cual si buscas ese atributo

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Atributos